# Partial page rendering not working

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

How to achieve only partial the body content ?

I have configured Spring tiles in my application by following below blog
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse/

Now i want only to render only body content and i want to keep header,menu and footer static.

How to do this please help me.

I tried to achieve using below code but not successfull

`Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
   elementId: "page1",
   formId: "page1Form",
   event: "onclick",
   params: {fragments: "body"}
}));`

Thanks in advance.